# Matlab Workspace: how to best handle multiple activities and save

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab and working through voice emotion recognition and have created folders for each emotion (7).
I am now working through FFT filtering and neural network training for each emotion.

Is it best to create a new Workspace for each emotion then save the Workspace to emotions folder?

There is the potential for variables clashes if I use the one Workspace,
or can anyone suggest a tidy way to work for ease of recall etc.

Comment: try to use structs - save each emotion data into different sttruct and save it to .mat file: `save(['emotion' num2str(n) '.mat'],['emotion' num2str(n) '_struct'])`

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.